# How to pass an array with id's from one component to another (angular)

Tags: javascript, html, angular, components, data-sharing

hello friends this is my first question here.

i have this situation in an angular project i need to pass and array of id's from one component to another very diferent component, there is not relation between both i say this because all the questions that i have found says to use viewchild, input, output but i think i cant do that because when i click the button that takes the id's from the first component in an array should use the angular router to navigate to the other component so there is a way to do this?

btw: a friend told me to use url params but i has to be "x" number of id's so i dont know if its the right answer

sorry for my english i hope to be clear

Comment: Are those two components under a same parent component?

Answer (score 3):

Just create a service that holds your data in a variable and returns it to you when required as below

Service code:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable('root')
export class DataService {
  private dataArr = [];

  constructor(){}  

  setArrData(val){
    this.dataArr = [...val]; //creates a new reference 
  }

  getArrData(){
   return this.dataArr;
  }
}
```

---

Component that has array data and make sure you set data to service and start your route

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { DataService } from 'path to service file';

@Component({
  selector: 'component-that-has-array',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class ComponentOne  {
  name = 'Angular 6';
  constructor(private dataService :DataService){

  }

  data=["1","2"];
  dataService.setArrData(data);
}
```

---

Component that has to receive data, after routing

```
import { Component,OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { DataService } from 'path to service file';

@Component({
  selector: 'component-that-recieves-array',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class ComponentTwo implements OnInit  {
  constructor(private dataService :DataService){  }
  ngOnInit(){
   data=dataService.getArrData();
  }

}
```

Comment: this one is quite simple. great answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use BehaviorSubject from rxjs in order to share data between components

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs/BehaviorSubject';

@Injectable()
export class DataService {

  private dataSource = new BehaviorSubject<any>({});
  data = this.dataSource.asObservable();

  constructor() { }

  updatedDataSelection(data: any){
    this.dataSource.next(data);
  }

}
```

And in you component file:

```
//inject service into a component

...

dataService.data.subscribe(data => {
  //do what ever needs doing when data changes
})

...

//update the value of data in the service
dataService.updateData(newData);
```

Comment: I would not suggest him to do this because, he wanted it after a route and does not need to listen to the changes in array dynamically so I gave a simpler approach, which does not involve Subjects, if you are interested you can also checkout my answer